# What Stochastic Calculi Other Than Ito And Stratonovich Exist?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, numerical-methods, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

When learning about stochastic calculus, you typically encounter Ito and Stratonovich calculi, usually in that order. There are many differences between the two (Ito processes have better martingale and Markov properties, while Stratonovich processes obey the chain rule from ordinary calculus), but at the fundamental level, these differences stem from how the integrals of each calculus is defined:

- The Ito calculus is just integration using the forward Euler scheme: $$dX_t=a(t,X_t)dt + b(t,X_t)dW_t \Rightarrow$$ $$ X_t-X_0=\lim_{\Delta t\to 0}\Big(\sum_{n} a(t_n,X_{t_n}) (t_{n+1}-t_n) + \sum_{n} b(t_n,X_{t_n}) (W_{t_{n+1}}-W_{t_n}) \Big)$$
- The Stratonovich calculus is just integration using the Trapezoidal rule: $$dX_t=a(t,X_t)dt + b(t,X_t)\circ dW_t \Rightarrow$$ $$ X_t-X_0=\lim_{\Delta t\to 0}\Big(\sum_{n} \frac{a(t_{n+1},X_{t_{n+1}})+a(t_{n},X_{t_{n}})}{2} (t_{n+1}-t_n) + \sum_{n} \frac{b(t_{n+1},X_{t_{n+1}})+ b(t_n,X_{t_n})}{2} (W_{t_{n+1}}-W_{t_n}) \Big)$$

(The above are just rough sketches, especially the sum bounds. I denote Brownian motion by $W_t$, and $\Delta t=t_{n+1}-t_n$ is assumed constant above even though the actual time mesh is unimportant)

So...what happens if I choose another integration method, like Simpson's rule? Runge-Kutta? (I remember from Kloeden and Platen that R-K is not possible for some reason) Backward Euler? Et cetera? Is it even possible to do so? Will I end up with something reducible to Ito or Stratonovich, does it lead to "garbage" calculi (i.e. nothing of interest), or is there some other useful calculus out there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, the answer to this lies in quite a bit more advanced topic called [rough path theory](http://www.hairer.org/notes/RoughPaths.pdf) (beware: PDF).

A rough path is a way of "enhancing" a $\alpha$-Hölder continuous path with some extra information.

A **rough path** is an ordered pair, $\textbf{X}=(X, \mathbb{X})$ where $X\colon [0,T]\to V$ where $V$ is some Banach space (typically $\Bbb{R}$) and a second order process $\Bbb{X}\colon [0,T]^2\to V\otimes V$. The pair must satisfy $\Bbb{X}_{s,t}-\Bbb{X}_{s,u}-\Bbb{X}_{u,t}=X_{s,u}\otimes X_{u,t}$

The second order process *defines* the following integral:

$$\int_s^t X_{s,r}\otimes dX_r=\colon\Bbb{X}_{s,t}$$

Rough paths can be thought of as a generalization of Ito and Stratonovich calculus. We can have the Ito rough path, $(B,\Bbb{B}^{Ito})$ and the Stratonovich rough path, $(B,\Bbb{B}^{Strat})$.

So your question boils down to, "how many different types of Brownian motion rough paths are there?". And the answer is given in the PDF I linked you. The answer is given in example 4.13 (page 59). If you have the process $B$, which is $\alpha$-Hölder continuous, with an enhancement, $\Bbb{B}$, then you can always add on another $2\alpha$-Hölder continuous function.

Meaning you can invent any stochastic calculi you want just by adding functions. For example Stratonovich calculus is just Ito Calculus adding a term: $\Bbb{B}^{Strat}_{s,t}=\Bbb{B}^{Ito}_{s,t}+\frac12(t-s)I$.

I believe but cannot find proof that ALL such Brownian rough paths are functions added onto the Ito rough path.

EDIT: I asked my adviser and it is true that all Brownian rough paths are increments of functions added onto the Ito rough path and this is indeed true and not so bad to prove. Essentially, just take the difference between $\Bbb{B}^{Ito}$ and your rough path, and the triple difference should be $0$, which as a theorem implies the difference is the difference of two variables, or the increment of a function.

So this is indeed an IFF.

Comment: This turned out to be surprisingly much deeper than I anticipated…thank you for the enlightening answer and the link (that pdf will keep me busy for a while).

Comment: @A.Sh beware that rough paths are very advanced. The book is as gentle an introduction as you can ask for though.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Worst-case scenario, I get something to look forward to understand someday…

Comment: Very interesting. I don't understand what you mean by the right hand side of $\Bbb{X}_{s,t}-\Bbb{X}_{s,u}-\Bbb{X}_{u,t}=X_{s,u}\otimes X_{u,t}$ ? What is ${X}_{u,t}$ ? I thought $X$ was defined on $[0,T]$.

Comment: @w.volante just $X_t-X_u$.

Comment: Is the order of $t,u,s$ in $[0,T]$ important ? What kind of operation is $\otimes$ ? I would love to read a very simple introduction to this subject, for $V=\mathbb R$. Any recommendations ? The pdf you linked is maybe a bit hard for me.

Comment: @w.volante the order does not matter. That operation is just tensor/outer product. No introduction to this subject will be simple, much less very simple. :) I asked about rough paths on here before so check my history for some explanations. Probably the best thing you can do to learn rough paths has nothing to do with rough paths. Do you know fractional Brownian motion? Study its analytic properties and in particular SDEs driven by fBm. For $H<1/2$ understand why we can't define solutions and why we need rough paths.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look into it. For now, I am trying to understand your argument that every Brownian rough paths (what is the precise definition of this ?) are functions added to the Ito rough path.

Comment: @W.Volante It was not really an argument, just a statement and maybe sketch. A Brownian rough path is a rough path where the first component is Brownian motion.

Comment: How would you write the second order process in the case of a one dimensional Brownian motion for both Ito and Stratonovitch rough path ?

Comment: @W.Volante It's the Ito or Stratovnovich integral

Comment: I meant in both scenarios, how would you write it in the case of a real one dimensional Brownian motion

Comment: @W.Volante Exactly what the Ito or Stratonovich integral gives you - just compute it

Comment: So I should compute $\int_s^t B(r) - B(s) dB(r)$ ?

Comment: @W.Volante Yes that is the second order process in the case of Ito Brownian motion

Comment: Isn't that cheating ? The second order process is supposed to define the  iterated integral, not the other way around ?

Comment: @w.Volante it is not cheating although it might seem like that. We have to define the second order process, which then defines the (pathwise) iterated integral. However we choose to define the second order process is fine, even using different types of integrals!